# Abstract Algebra (FUNCTIONS)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Give an example of a function f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} with the property that there exists a function  g:N → N such that the composition g∘f is the identity function on
N, but for no function h : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} does it hold that f∘h is the identity function
on N.

Solution: Example of a function

```
          x∈N  than f(x)∈N and g(x)∈N
          thus f(x)=x^{2} 
               and that 
               g(x)= √x ,x is a square or  0, otherwise = f(x)^-1 inverse of f(x)
```

If S is any set, we will use idS or id to denote the identity mapping from S to itself. Define this map by id(s) = s for all s∈S. A map g : B → A is an inverse mapping of f : A → B if gof = idA and fog = idB; in other words, the inverse function of a function simply "undoes" the function. A map is said to be invertible if it has an inverse. We usually write f^-1 for the inverse of f.

[image: function f and g]

[image: function g0f]

** but for no function h:N → N does it hold that f∘h is the identity function
on N.**

for a no function h:N → N it does not hold that f∘h is a identity on N.
To my own understanding if h is a no function than therefore we cannot map N to N because there is no function to generate codomain or image of f.

**please help me out if my solution is on the right path. Thank you!**

Comment: Did you mean for the second $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ to be $h : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Give an example of a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ with the property that there exists](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684524/give-an-example-of-a-function-f-mathbbn-rightarrow-mathbbn-with-the-pr)

Comment: @Brian: I wonder if they're in the same class.

Comment: yes Snowball that is what i meant, thank you

Answer (score 3):

When thinking about the existence of inverses, it's a good idea to start by thinking about whether a function is one-to-one or onto.

For example, if $f$ is not onto, then no function $h$ can be a right inverse to $f$.  Likewise, if $f$ is not one-to-one, then $f$ cannot have a left inverse.

Think of it like this.  A left inverse $g$ has the property that it reverses the action of $f$:
$$g\circ f = \textrm{id}.$$
But if $f$ is not one-to-one, then some information is lost when $f$ is applied.  What I mean by this is that if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then if we observe the value $f(x_1)$, we cannot know whether the input value was $x_1$ or $x_2$.  So, for instance, when we consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ (this is everyone's favorite example of a non-one-to-one function), application of the function loses the sign of $x$. Knowing that $f(x)=4$ allows us to infer that either $x=2$ or $x=-2$, but we cannot know which one. For $g$ to be the left inverse of $f$, it would sometimes need to satisfy $f(4)=2$, and sometimes $g(4)=-2$.  But this is absurd, so no such $g$ can exist.

The situation with a right inverse is similar.  If $f$ is the right inverse of some function $h$, then $f$ undoes the action of $h$.  But if $f$ is not onto, then there are some values in the domain of $h$ that $f$ just cannot reach!  For example, if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is again $f(x)=x^2$, then there cannot be any function $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ for which $f\circ h=\textrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}}$. For suppose there was such a $h$ - where could it take $-1$?  If $f\circ h=\textrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}}$, then $f\circ h(-1)=-1$, which in turn would mean $h(-1)^2=-1$. But $-1$ has no real square roots (it is not in the range of $f$), so no matter where $h$ takes $-1$, it is not possible for $h$ to be the right inverse of $f$.

So where does this leave you>  You want your $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ to have a left inverse, so it must be one-to-one.  But it cannot have a right inverse, so it cannot be onto. See if you can take it from here.